# What is a contractive mapping vs contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

This is an example from a text to show that this mapping does not have a fixed point because it is contractive but not a contraction:

[image]

I am not sure what the difference is between contractive and contraction. Doesn't the function satisfy all the requirements of the fixed point theorem/

Answer (score 2):

A *contraction map* is a map $f$ such that there exists a $0 \le k < 1$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le k|x - y|$$
for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain.

A *contractive map*, also called a *shrinking map*, is a map $f$ for which
$$|f(x) - f(y)| < |x - y|$$
for all $x$ and $y$ in the domain.  Not all contractive maps are contraction maps, as the example points out.  Although contraction maps must have a (unique) fixed point, contractive maps may not have any fixed point.

On compact metric spaces, contractive and contraction maps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

another example, the hyperbola (upper branch)
$$  3y^2 - 4yx + x^2 = 5 $$ or
$$  y=\frac{2x+\sqrt{15+x^2}}{3}$$
When $x\geq 0,$  we see $\sqrt{15+x^2} > x$ so that $2x+\sqrt{15+x^2} > 3x$

The trouble occurs because the derivative gets arbitrarily close to $1$
$$  y'=\frac{x+2\sqrt{15+x^2}}{3\sqrt{15+x^2}}$$
as $x$ increases without bound